# What is the plural of "ostrich"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I've noticed that it is often "ostriches" or "ostrich" according to different sources. Does it vary by the dialect of English?

Normally I'd use Google to determine something like this, but unfortunately the search for "ostrich" plural is overcounted because of references to the singular "ostrich".

Dictionaries laying around were
inconclusive. One listed plural as
"ostrich" another listed "ostriches". In
cases where the dictionaries disagree or
where there are multiple possible
solutions I tend to go with the more common answer. That is something
that can be easily found by googling,
but not in this case

Comment: Just wondering.... Is there any reason why you prefer googling over referencing a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries laying around were inconclusive. One listed plural as "ostrich" another listed "ostriches". In cases where the dictionaries disagree or where there are multiple possible solutions I tend to go with the more common answer. That is something that can be easily found by googling, but not in this case.

Comment: Google Ngrams shows that the number of hits is roughly balanced between "two ostrich" and "two ostriches", as well as "four ostrich" and "four ostriches". [Three](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+ostrich%2Cthree+ostriches%2Cthree+ostrich+feathers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) is an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where the plural occurs in the citations in the OED, it is *ostriches*. However, those who make *ostrich* the plural can appeal to the precedent of the hunter’s plural in *lion, tiger, elephant* and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The plural of ostrich is ostriches. [source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ostrich)

Comment: But according this *New York Times* article, owners prefer the plural *ostrich*: "the plural of the bird can be either ostrich or ostriches but owners prefer ostrich for both singular and plural" [http://www.gourmetostrich.com/theneworktimes.html ]

Comment: Do you own an ostrich?

Comment: To which I reply that other dictionaries indicate that the plural is either "ostrich" or "ostriches". http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/ostrich (from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language)

Comment: @user545424: No, but maybe I own ostrich. :)

Comment: @Pridkett, then go with either one. What are you worried about? If it's the ostrich farmers, then I'd stick with ostrich.

Comment: @user545424: Supposing I was writing a story or screenplay and wanted the dialog to be authentic, it would be important to know the nuances of usage. JLG established that ostrich owners prefer "ostrich", which is helpful. I'm wondering if that's related to the differences between dialects of English. For example, would a South African say "ostrich" or "ostriches"? What about an Englishman in 1928 Mandatory Mesopotamia who saw several members of the Struthio camelus syriacus species gathered in one location?

Comment: @Pridkett, fair enough, but I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a single person on earth who would find it detracting from a story to read that a character misused the plural form of ostrich in their native dialect. Unless it was an ostrich farmer reading about ostrich farmers, in which case you better stick with ostrich.