# Strange plural pairs

Tags: collective-nouns, irregular-plurals, pluralia-tantum

I don't speak German but was fascinated to learn that in (Swiss or I believe Bavarian) German *Rahm* means cream, but *Rahmen* means frame - despite adding "*-en*" being the normal way to make a singular word plural. *Rahm* apparently has no plural (and/or is the same in the plural, like the English "sheep") and *Rahmen* is the same (i.e. the words for frame and frames are the same).

So I set out to find similar examples in English, i.e. where:

1. Word 2 looks like the plural of Word 1, but is not
2. Word 1 either is its own plural or has no separate plural
3. Word 2 either is its own plural or has no separate plural

The closest I can find are:

- *physic* (medicinal drugs - apparently it's own plural - or the study of medicine), and *physics* (the branch of science concerned with the nature and properties of matter and energy, having no plural).
- *corp* (corporation) and *corps* (body of people). Doesn't quite work as if "*corp*" is a word, I think it has "*corps*" as a plural which would break rule 2.

Can you do better?

Comment: To my (British) mind, *corp* is an abbreviation - not a word in its own right!  I had never heard of *physic* - but have now checked it in a dictionary!

Comment: _Corps_ is a borrowing from French and pronounced in the French manner, with the 'ps' silent.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree - I was looking at the written word. _physic_ is better, as I'm not sure '_corp_' is a word as opposed to an abbreviation (as pointed out by @TrevorD)

Answer (score 2):

How about (the) [*new*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/new)  (new things; a noun that has no plural) and [*news*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/news) (information or reports about recent events; another noun that has no plural)?

Comment: Almost, but violates rule 2 as _mew_ has a plural (_mews_)

Comment: @abligh So, I changed a letter.

Comment: Yup - that works!

Answer (score 2):

> [Specie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/specie): coins, especially those made of valuable metals.

This has no plural, because it's an uncountable noun.

> [Species](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/species): a set of animals or plants, members of which have similar characteristics to each other and which can breed with each other.

The plural form of *species* is unchanged.

Comment: This *specie* is uncountable and *species* is its own plural. So this is not an example of the plural form of one word being similar to the singular of another. It is just two words that differ by one having an *s* on the end. They are, however, related etymologically, since [*specie*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specie#Noun) is the ablative singular of Latin *species*. But there is another [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specie#Noun_2) as an erroneous singular of *species* but that just a word that may or may not vary in the singular as *fish* may or may not vary in the plural.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: This is very similar to the German example the OP gave: *Rahm* and *specie* have no plural, and *Rahmen* and *species* are unchanged in their plural forms.

Comment: My mistake, Peter. I totally misread the question. I just assumed the OP was looking for an *actual* word that was the singular of one word and the plural of another. That would be more interesting but there may be no valid example in English or German. The examples I gave in my answer, that work only in spoken English may be the nearest you get.

Comment: But both the *Rahm* and *specie* examples rely on these words not having separate plurals, and thus allowing us to hypothesise the plurals. If you allow hypothetical plurals if words declined differently from how they do, then *boot* would appear to be a valid example. If it declined like *foot* then its plural would be *beet* which is a singular noun with plural *beets*. (Note that *foot* does rhyme with *boot* in some dialects.)

Answer (score 1):

(The) [*rich*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rich) (rich people considered together as a group; plural only) and [*riches*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/riches) (a large amount of money or valuable possessions; also plural only) satisfy your 1-3, as *riches* looks like the plural of (the already plural) *rich* (cf. *ostrich*, or if you want to avoid an [argument](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/64045/42179) about that, then perhaps *bitch*).

Comment: Yup! that's one.

Answer (score 0):

*[Math](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/math)* and *[maths](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maths)* are both nouns that have no plural.

Answer (score -1):

It is a feature of English that our spelling is so erratic that it is very difficult to find an example that works for both the spoken and written forms. Either the spoken forms match and the written forms don't - or vice versa. For example, if you start the noun [**may**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/may#Noun_2) (Note this link does not look stable - it is meant to point to the "maid" definition as that is a countable noun) then you have a choice:

You can add the letter **s** which works as a spoken example but fails orthographically (**maze** or **maize**, so a double example) or you can add the *sound* **/s/** which again fails because we spell **mace** with a **c** and pronounce **mays** with a /z/.

There are plenty of examples like this. Here are a few:

> doe/does/dose/doze
>   rye/ryes/rice/rise
>   pea/peas/peace-piece/pease

The problem is caused not only by the general erraticness of English spelling but also by the specific problem of having two pronunciations for **s** and several spellings for each of those two sounds. We can see this because if we used **en** as a plural marker as often as German does then it might be easier to find examples: if, for example, there were a singular noun that sounded like **oxen** it would almost certainly be written the same way too.

Of the examples above, **pease** requires special mention: it is an uncountable noun that refers to a seed used in cooking, in the same way as barley. And they made a pudding from it called **please pudding**. But because it was seeds it looked countable, and because it ended with a **/z/** it sounded plural and the plural **peas** was born, from which we get the singular [**pea**] (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pea#Etymology_1) so this almost-example is based on a singular being misunderstood as a plural.